# Treif knife with kosher cream cheese

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

Can one spread kosher cream cheese with a treif knife? I'm looking for sources (obviously will AYCLOP for final psak)
Thank you,

Comment: [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887), user16768. Thanks for bringing your question here.

Comment: http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chapter-96/

Comment: Does this cream cheese have onion chunks?

Answer (score 3):

If the knife is cold and clean, and the cream cheese doesn't contain onions/hot peppers, then this is permitted.

R Yitzchok Yaakov Fuchs (in his book [Hakashrut](https://www.eichlers.com/hakashrut-rav-yitzchok-yaakov-fuchs-hardcover.html), p. 668) writes

> A completely clean knife that is found in a non-kosher kitchen may be
>   used to cut cold fruit and vegetables however it may not be used to cut
>   sharp foods.

R Binyamin Tabady and R Yonathan Jessurun both told me they permitted this on a one-off basis, i.e., not something to be done regularly.

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: I heard in the name of Rav Herschel Schachter that this knife can be used once every thirty days